# How to run zend framework project on portable wamp or xampp?

Tags: zend-framework, xampp, project, wamp, portability

I am trying to run (without succes) a zend framework project with portable wamp. (I'm having the same problem with the portable version of xampp.)

Usually I get error HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error), as well as

`"There is no such file Zend/Application.php in public/index.php line 18 (require_once 'Zend/Application.php').`

Without the portable version of wamp I have no problems. I have changed the DocumentRoot from `www` to public folder from my project in `httpd.conf` and the project runs well in the browser.

I tried to do the same thing within the portable version of wamp (and xampp) - no result. Unfortunately I can only install portable software on my computer from work, so I would appreciate it a lot if someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Portable or not it makes really no difference. You seems to forgot to tune your LAMP environment. Most likely your httpd got .htaccess handling restricted, or mod_rewrite is not enabled thus httpd fails while trying to parse your project's .htaccess. Check your httpd's error log and/or php error log.

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. After checking httpd's error log, I found in httpd's error log:[ssl:warn] [pid 5340:tid 216] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache] and other errors all connected with load of Zend_Session. I've tried to open another project whcih doesn't contain any Zend_Session and it works! Now I'm trying to solve the issue with ssl. Maybe You know the solution, so I'd be able to include Zend_Session classes in my project? Thank You!